# I have an encrypted partition for the which I need to recover the passphrase to recover data

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption, data-recovery

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 along side Ubuntu Studio 14.04.  My Ubuntu works well but I have all my data on the Ubuntu Studio partition - that I can no longer access.

How can I recover the partition and the passphrase that goes along with it?

Ubuntu on sda1
Ubuntu Studio on sda6

Comment: If you remember the password from the Studio setup, can you try `ecryptfs-recover-private`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover a forgotten passphrase. If you could then an attacker would be able to use the same process to get unauthorised access to your data which would defeat the purpose of the encryption.